# How do I create a nested list where each sublist is different and can be called upon without deleting the previous sublist?

Tags: c#

I am going to try my hardest to describe what I want the output to look like.

Basically I want a list that contain a list of numbers. Each sublist can be string additional numbers while the list itself can string additional lists of the sublist.

This is what I visualize the list to be like

List = {list[0] = {2,4,6,8...etc}, list[1]={3,6,9,12...etc}, list[2]{4,8,12,16...etc}........}.

The thing is the list and the sublist needs to store as much as info as the user desires.

I tried to create a nested list by using `List<List<int>>` and sublist. Its not working as planned. If i use sublist.Add, the sublists keeps growing and when I assign the sublist to the main list, I am just adding the same list over and over again. If I use sublist.Empty, then the previous main list will only remember the newest thing that has been added.
I know this is confusing, but i don't know how else to describe the error.

Comment: How does the user decide which sublist to add a number to? By index?

Comment: Show your code. Each time you add a sublist, you have to create it with `new`. Ex: `mainList.Add(new List<int>());`

Comment: by index or by order of List.Add() @itsme86

Comment: "I know this is confusing" - Yes, show the code that didn't work. Use more C#, less English.

Comment: Also it might be helpful if you describe what you are doing with this data. It's possible that a `List<List<int>>` is not the best object for what you're doing.

Comment: your previous code works,but you can only assign any number of int to one list at a time. Pretend that you created a random number generator between 1 and 500, a 1000 times. You want a list of numbers that are divisible by 11 and 13 only, and at the end of the 1000 iteration, you compare the total of the two list to see which one is bigger. @Rufus L

Comment: @JimRoberts - Added a new answer below for your example

Comment: @JimRoberts as the most-voted answer refers to your comment rather than your question, you should update your question. Also, for future references, this is what is known as an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your comment above, I would use a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` instead of a `List<List<int>>`. You could use a `List<List<int>>` as you originally did, but a `Dictionary` makes lookup easier, since you can define something more meaningful for the `Key` of each `List` rather than tracking the `index` of each `List`. A `string` or `Enum` key would also be good in some situations.

Here is how I would do it:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // The dictionary 'key' contains the 'divisible by' number
    // The dictionary 'value' is the list of numbers divisible by the key
    var results = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    // This list holds the ints that we care about for finding 'divisible by' counts
    var divisors = new List<int> {11, 13};

    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        // Generate a random number
        var randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 501);

        // Check if it's divisible by any of the ints we care about
        foreach (var divisor in divisors.Where(d => randomNumber % d == 0))
        {
            // If it is, add or update the list at that key with this number
            if (results.ContainsKey(divisor))
            {
                results[divisor].Add(randomNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                results[divisor] = new List<int> { randomNumber };
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Here is a comparison of the list counts:");

    foreach (var divisor in divisors)
    {
        var countOfThisItem = (results.ContainsKey(divisor))
            ? results[divisor].Count
            : 0;

        Console.WriteLine($"Numbers divisible by {divisor}: {countOfThisItem}");
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to quit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

For completeness, and to answer your original question, here's how I would do it with a `List<List<int>>`:

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Create a parent list with two child lists
    // The first one will track numbers divisible by 11
    // The second one will track numbers divisible by 13
    var parentList = new List<List<int>>
    {
        new List<int>(),
        new List<int>()
    };

    var rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        // Generate a random number
        var randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 501);

        if (randomNumber % 11 == 0)
        {
            parentList[0].Add(randomNumber);
        }
        if (randomNumber % 13 == 0)
        {
            parentList[1].Add(randomNumber);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Here is a comparison of the list counts:");
    Console.WriteLine($"Numbers divisible by 11: {parentList[0].Count}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Numbers divisible by 13: {parentList[1].Count}");            

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to quit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

Here's an example where you have a random number of players, each of whom has a number of hands (there can be more than one due to splitting). Each hand has some number of cards (values 1 to 13).

Note that I added some code to automatically give approximately 25% of the hands a pair, and I added code to always split if there is a pair, because otherwise splits were too rare. :)

Also note that you would need to do real 'card math' instead of what I have below. Currently Kings are 13 points, Aces are always 1, etc...

```
private static void Main()
{
    // Players is a list of people playing, each of whom have
    // a list of hands (they may have more than one in the
    // case of a split), and each hand has a list of cards
    var players = new List<List<List<int>>>();

    var rnd = new Random();

    // Generate a random number of players and deal them each a card
    var numPlayers = rnd.Next(1, 51);
    for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
    {
        // Generate the first hand for each player
        players.Add(new List<List<int>> {new List<int> {rnd.Next(1, 14)} });
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Welcome! We have {players.Count} people playing today.");

    // Deal next card to each player, randomly split pairs, and finish each players hand
    foreach (var playerHands in players)
    {
        // Let player split as often as they can (continue to play
        // hands while they have a hand with one card in it)
        while (playerHands.Any(cardsInHand => cardsInHand.Count == 1))
        {
            foreach (var hand in playerHands.Where(cardsInHand => cardsInHand.Count == 1).ToList())
            {
                var cardInHand = hand[0];
                var drawnCard = rnd.Next(1, 14);

                // I added this code to automatically give them a pair 25% of the time 
                var forcePair = rnd.Next(1, 5) % 4 == 0; 
                if (forcePair)
                {
                    drawnCard = cardInHand;
                }

                if (drawnCard == cardInHand) // They drew a pair
                {
                    // Randomly determine if they will split this hand
                    var splitThisHand = rnd.Next(1, 3) % 2 == 0; // If the number is even, we split

                    // Override random determination and always split on pairs
                    splitThisHand = true;

                    if (splitThisHand)
                    {
                        // Create a new hand for this player and add the card to it
                        playerHands.Add(new List<int> { drawnCard });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Add the card to the existing hand
                        hand.Add(drawnCard);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // Add the card to the existing hand
                    hand.Add(drawnCard);
                }
            }                    
        }

        // Finish playing each hand
        foreach (var hand in playerHands)
        {
            var handValue = hand.Sum();

            // hit if less than 17
            while (handValue < 17)
            {
                var drawnCard = rnd.Next(1, 14);
                hand.Add(drawnCard);
                handValue += drawnCard;
            }
        }
    }

    // Output all the players statistics
    for (int i = 0; i < players.Count; i++)
    {
        var playerHands = players[i];
        Console.WriteLine($"Player #{i + 1} has {playerHands.Count} hands");
        for(int h = 0; h < playerHands.Count; h++)
        {
            var hand = playerHands[h];
            Console.WriteLine(
                $" - Hand #{h + 1} has a value of {hand.Sum()}, containing the cards: {string.Join(", ", hand)}");                    
        }
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone!\nPress any key to quit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for guiding me. I just have some follow up questions. For the second block of code that you showed me. Is it possible to modify it so that the parent list can be dynamic as well without having to initialize it within the curly bracket first, but at the same time keep still keeping the daughters lists dynamic @Rufus L

Comment: @JimRoberts - Yes, just like any other `List`, it can be empty when you initialize it and you can add and remove items from it. It just happens that the items it contains are other `List` objects.

Comment: Pretend your are playing black jack, except the deck isn't shuffled it is generated. So the possibility of having a 3 or 3000 split hands exists however unlikely it may be. I want to keep that possibility open. Each of those split hands needs its own List to keep track of the dealt cards and there needs to be a encompassing array to keep track of how many split hands I manage to split so far. @ Rufus L

Comment: @JimRoberts I see. Lists are dynamic by nature, so you can definitely add and remove items from them on the fly. If I understand you correctly, you have a parent list of players, and each player has a list of hands, and each hand has a list of cards. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes but you don't need to have a list of players, it is just you and the dealer. You just need to have a list of hands and each hand has to have a list of cards.The problem is the list of hands can vary due to the randomly generated cards it cards. Upon researching this question some said that, you need to declare the number of elements in the list of hands first. But I have no way of knowing that number @ Rufus L

Comment: @JimRoberts No, you don't need to declare the number of elements for a list. I've added an example that shows how you might do this. Hoewever, I am tracking number of players, too, so it's slightly more complicated, but not too bad.

Comment: @JimRoberts - did this help?

Comment: Yes, Thank you  for your time. I really appreciate it . There are a lot of different things in your code I haven't learned yet and Its going to take time to digest it. @Rufus L